# Differentiate between sent and received MMS when using content://mms-sms/conversations

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mms

I need to know when an MMS is sent and when one is received.  Registering for a broadcast receiver didn't seem to work for me, so I am trying to observe `content://mms-sms/conversations`.  When `onChange()` occurs, how do I differentiate between a sent and a received MMS?  The columns I can see don't seem to give me any clue.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? i'm in the same boat now

Comment: You have to experiment with the various content providers on your particular device since they are undocumented and unsupported for app developer use.  What I did was listen for onChange() on content://mms-sms/conversations/ as the "trigger" but then actually query the content://mms provider for the actual data.  Then I would check what folder the message was in (inbox, sent, draft, etc.) to determine its status.

Comment: how do you check what folder it's in? what do you mean by that